# Passing std::function<bool (int)> by value

Tags: c++, windows, macos

I was trying to expose

```
typedef std::function<bool (int)> Filter;
```

that is part of

```
#include <functional>
```

such that user can create the Filter and pass it into my component for processing. The requirement demands that the processing cannot be done in a templated function.

I understand that using STL on interfaces is not a good practice as the size of Filter type is STL implementation dependent. What are my alternate options but for a **raw function pointer**, or a **functor that is received by a templated function**.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what exactly are the problems? What doen't work and what are you trying to do?

Comment: "*What are my alternate options but for...*" You could implement your own version of `std::function`. Also, "*I understand that using STL on interfaces is not a good practice as the size of Filter type is STL implementation dependent.*" Why does that matter at all? Who cares how big `std::function` is; your code is not going to fail due to the object's size. The only concern with interfaces comes from *dll* interfaces, where C++ is essentially forbidden.

Comment: @Nicol: interesting that BigBoss disagrees, and is prepared to use limited C++ in the interface. Basically, he's willing to assume an ABI that permits a class with virtual functions but doesn't dictate the layout of the whole standard libraries.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas : `The only concern with interfaces comes from dll interfaces, where C++ is essentially forbidden.` : "essentially forbidden" feels a bit too much. This problem only arises if you mix DLLs compiled with different runtimes/compilers/standard libraries. DLLs compiled with the same compiler (same all), with a dynamic runtime (/MD or /MDd in VC++) have no such problems. I'm currently working on a 300+ DLL and EXE project, all using STL or other templates in their interfaces, without any problem at all. Boost delivers a bunch of DLLs, too, in addition to their template-heavy headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Size if not really very important here, but you are right if some one that use your library use a different implementation of STL, then it will fail to use your code, so what's another option? I will use an interface (pure virtual class) for this:

```
struct MyCallback {
    virtual bool filter( int ) = 0;
};
class MyImplementation {
public:
    ...
    void set_callbacks( MyCallback* );
};
```

Using this architecture you can let your user to use power of C++ and at same time you do not depend on STL!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass function pointer as result of `std::bind`. For example:

```
typedef std::function<bool (int)> Filter;

bool Foo(int i)
{
    return i == 0;
}

void BarCaller(Filter bar) //pass by value
{
   bar(2);
}

Filter bar = std::bind(&Foo, std::placeholders::_1); //now you can pass bar wherever you want
BarCaller(bar);
```

Comment: This is redundant, `std::function` is perfectly capable of handling function pointers.

Comment: He tried to pass them by value as i understood and showed how to achieve it

Comment: As I understand the question, it is really about how to declare `BarCaller` so it does not take an argument of type `std::function<bool (int)>`, nor a template argument, nor a naked function pointer.

Comment: @Denis, Is the bar object safe to pass between two components that may potentially have different STL implementation dependency? This is typical if one is built on Visual studio 2008 and another with 2010 for example.

Answer (score 1):

C-style callback interfaces are usually done by passing two values -- a function pointer and a user data pointer. You can fancy this up by wrapping it in a struct if you like.

So, if you want your dll interface to remain C-style, provide a means to wrap a `std::function` in that pair. Something like:

```
bool c_style_callback(void *userdata, int n) {
    return (*static_cast<const Filter*>(userdata))(n);
}
```

You can provide a convenience function in a header file, that runs in the calling dll and provides the interface you really want:

```
inline void register_callback(const Filter &filter) {
   register_c_style_callback(c_style_callback, static_cast<void*>(&filter));
}
```

I have been lazy and made it the caller's responsibility to ensure that `filter` remains valid for as long as the callback is registered. You could fix that by dynamically allocating a copy of it, and adding code to retrieve and free it when the callback is deregistered (again, this code runs in the calling dll). If deregistering is initiated by the caller then you'd need some kind of handle representing the registered callback.

The laziness pays off if `Filter` is a predicate passed to an algorithm that doesn't use it again after returning. It's only when the filter is registered indefinitely that you need a whole mechanism to manage lifetime.

Comment: Steve, the only problem I see is the ugly looking 
"void * "
I know this is the c style callback and void* is the bread and butter. I was hoping for something more elegant. +1 for the effort. Thanks.